# Stuck on a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am running MYSQL 5.1.41 on Ubuntu 10.04.

I have two tables. stocks which contains basic info about a group of stocks and has the following columns: pk, name, pur_date, pur_price, avg_vol, mkt_cap. The other table is data which contains price history about the stocks in the stocks table. The data table contains the following columns: pk, ticker, date, open,high, low, close, volume, adj_close.

I need a query that will show the high for a stock since it's purchase date and the date it occurred.

I have this query:

```
SELECT ticker, date, MAX(high)
FROM data, stocks
WHERE ticker = sym AND date > pur_date 
GROUP BY  ticker
ORDER BY ticker
LIMIT 0, 100
```

The query will give me each stocks high but always returns the latest date in the data table, which happens to be 2011-12-23.  How do I change the query to show the date the stock reached its high?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This type of question is asked many times per week on Stack Overflow.  Follow the `greatest-n-per-group` tag I've added, and read some of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

That's the classic `greatest-per-group` issue.  One solution is to query the maximum `high` for the ticket in a subquery:

```
select  ticker
,       date
,       high
from    data d
join    stocks s
on      d.ticker = s.sym
where   d.date > pur_date
        and d.high = 
        (
        select  max(high)
        from    data d2
        where   d2.ticker = d.ticker
               and d2.date > pur_date
        )
```

See Quassnoi's [explain extended blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/25/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-resolving-ties/) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the working example. Also thanks to you and the other posters for the links to better help me understand what was wrong with my query.

Answer (score 0):

You originally had your grouping by stock ticker, which may not give the correct expected results as I'll explain later.  I've actually done a pre-query on a per purchase stock entry and getting the highest price since it was purchased...  Consider the following scenario.

Person buys 100 Shares of Stock X on Jan 1 for $20 per share.  Buys ANOTHER set of 100 shares on Jan 25 at $23 per share, and another 100 on Feb 18 at $24 per share.  The actual data shows Stock X had a high on Jan 22 (before second purchase) of $27 per share then dropped by the time the $23 on Jan 25... shifted down/up from there before Feb purchase, but only on Feb 27 did it kick back up to $25 per share.

The first trade
Jan 1  Bought $20 would show a high of $27 on Jan 22
Jan 25 Bought $23 would show the high of $25 on Feb 27
Feb 18 Bought $24 would also show high of $25 on Feb 27

So grouping by ticker might not necessarily show.  Now, above scenario being shown, would you want from here that Stock X across-the-board for all purchases showed a high of $27? even though the most recent purchases never saw that price?

```
select 
      s2.*,
      d2.*
   from 
      ( select 
              s.pk,
              s.sym,
              max( d.high ) as HighSincePurchDay
           from
              stocks s
                 join data d
                    on s.sym = d.ticker
                   AND s.pur_date <= d.date
           group by
              s.pk
      ) PreQuery

      JOIN stocks s2
         on PreQuery.PK = s2.PK

      JOIN data d2
         on PreQuery.Sym = d.Ticker
        AND s.Pur_Date <= d.Date
        AND d.high = PreQuery.HighSincePurchDay
```